# IE8 getJSON cached data

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8

Simply one really. IE8 is caching my data so it works first time but not afterwards. I need to  stop it using cached data when i call getJSON?

P.S Im currently debuging my site in IE so expect lots of posts from me :) Thanks for all that have helped so far truely are a great help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call this before your `.getJSON` call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an HTTP header to disable caching from your server-side script.